# Adicionar admob após uma ListView em um RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, admob

Boa Noite!

Estou tentando adicionar um admob ao final de uma ListView em um RelativeLayout e o banner não aparece de jeito nenhum! Já tentei mexer de diversas maneiras no layout para ver se a ListView não estava cobrindo o admob, mas não resolveu em nada. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o xml abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="64dp"
    android:paddingRight="64dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Suas Faltas"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/vazio"
        android:text="Nenhuma matéria inserida"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar um `LinearLayout`, veja se está solução te ajuda.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="64dp"
    android:paddingRight="64dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Suas Faltas"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vazio"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Nenhuma matéria inserida"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, além de não aparecer o adview, desorganizou a apresentacao da listView :(